# How to fix "val cannot be reassigned" error in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose and I need help. When trying to add a modifier to a column I get an error that says "val cannot be reassigned" I know that a val is immutable but I cannot find out where the val is defined.

Here is the import list

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.testapplication.ui.theme.TestApplicationTheme
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            TestApplicationTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column {
        modifier = Modifier
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    TestApplicationTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column {
        modifier = Modifier
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
}
```

You are getting modifier as parameter in this function, then you are trying to re-assign its value with `modifier = Modifier` . This will give you error because "modifier" is already defined.

To add modifier to a Column you should use its parameters. Ex;

```
Column(modifier = Modifier) {...}
```